# Why are my Azure Data Factory Stored Procedures Timing Out after 30 Minutes?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, timeout, azure-data-factory

Why are my Azure Data Factory Stored Procedures Timing Out after 30 Minutes?

Here is the Azure SQL Linked Service definition:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "Server=tcp:db1.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDb;User ID=User;Password=***;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=120"
            }
       },
        "connectVia": {
            "type": "integrationRuntimeReference",
            "referenceName": "shir-01"
        }
    },
    "name": "LinkedService"
}
```

And, here is the Pipeline definition:

```
{
    "name": BulkLoad11_Pipeline",
    "properties": {
                "activities": [
                {
                "name": "BulkLoad",
                        "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                        "policy": {
                    "timeout": {
                "value": "1.00:00:00",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[BulkLoad]",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "FileName": {
                            "value": "FILE11",
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "LinkedService",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I trigger the Pipeline, it fails at 30 minutes with a TimeOut error:

```
Activity BulkLoad failed: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period
elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```